# CSS inconsistently functions in Awesomium

Tags: c#, jquery, css, wpf, awesomium

I am using Awesomium 1.6.5 to render the majority of my application's user interface, and have noticed some inconsistencies in CSS loading. The very first time the window is opened, CSS will function normally and styles will be loaded.

However, past that point, whether the styles apply appears to be random. The window on the left shows the styles functioning correctly, and the window on the right shows the styles failing.

[image: CSS inconsistencies]

As these buttons are jQuery UI (1.10.1 with jQuery 1.9.1), my first thought was that the JavaScript which would create these buttons wasn't being executed, so I moved that from inside the HTML of the page to the application, ensuring that the JavaScript is executed even before the user can see the page.

This made no difference, and the problem still persists.

All CSS (my stylesheets plus jQuery UI's stylesheet) are loaded at `WebCore` initialisation via `WebCoreConfig.CustomCSS`, which is passed to the `WebCore`. Pages being rendered do have some styles in their HTML (using the `<style>` tag).

The settings window class is a singleton which handles the instantiation and managing of the actual WPF window, and each time the method `SettingsWindow.Show()` is called, previous instances of the WPF window are closed (along with the Awesomium `WebControl`) and a new instance is created. After this instance is created, the appropriate JavaScript is executed. This is the `Initialise()` function:

```
// Host is an instance of AwesomiumHost, a WPF window containing an Awesomium
// WebControl control.
public static void Initialise()
{
    if (Host != null)
    {
        Host.webControl.Close();
        Host.Close();
    }

    Host = new AwesomiumHost(Resources.Markup.SettingsPage)
    {
        Width = 810,
        Height = 640,
        Title = "Settings"
    };

    var webControl = Host.webControl;

    webControl.ExecuteJavascript(Markup.jQuery);
    webControl.ExecuteJavascript(Markup.Cufon);
    webControl.ExecuteJavascript(Markup.CufonOpenSans);
    webControl.ExecuteJavascript(
        "Cufon.replace('.title, .section-hdr', { "
            + "color: '-linear-gradient(#555, #222)'"
        + " }); "
        + "Cufon.replace('.text');"
    );
    webControl.ExecuteJavascript("$(function() {"
        + "$( '#host-choice' ).buttonset();"
        + "$( '#backup-choice' ).buttonset();"
    + "});");
    webControl.ExecuteJavascript(
        "Cufon.replace('.title', { "
            + "color: '-linear-gradient(#555, #222)'"
        + " }); "
        + "Cufon.replace('.text');"
    );
    webControl.ExecuteJavascript(@"
    $(function() {
        $( '#host-choice' ).buttonset(); // Where jQuery should create the buttons
        $( '#backup-choice' ).buttonset();
    });");

    webControl.LoadCompleted += (s, e) =>
        webControl.ExecuteJavascript(
        "$('#x').click();");
    // Sets the state of the "No" button (shown in image) to "pressed."
}
```

So I ask, why would the buttons be inconsistently loading, and what can be done to fix this?

Comment: did you happen to figure this out?  Curious on this

Comment: I didn't, but moving to Awesomium 1.7.0.5 seems to have fixed it.